# Why I see X-Magento-Cache-Debug in production mode?

Tags: magento2, cache, full-page-cache, varnish

I have Varnish configured in my server and my project is running in **production mode**, even though, I continue seeing the debug tag `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` in the header.

[image: Magento 2 production mode]

[image: Magento 2 Varnish X-Magento-Cache-Debug]

According to [Devdocs - Varnish Final verification](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish-final.html) this header tag just show up in developer mode.

Why does it happen and how could I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` header is set by Varnish VCL itself. From a standard VCL:

```cpp
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }
    # ....
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    # ...
}
```

So its inclusion is dictated by presence of the header `X-Magento-Debug` which is set by Magento code [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.5-p1/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php#L64-L66):

```
            if ($this->state->getMode() == AppState::MODE_DEVELOPER) {
                $result->setHeader('X-Magento-Debug', 1);
            }
```

As you can decipher from the code above, Magento 2 sets the`X-Magento-Debug` header *for Varnish* when it's being run in developer mode.

"For Varnish" - taking note that few lines later (in VCL), the `X-Magento-Debug` is being unset and clients will only see the `X-Magento-Cache-Debug` header.

Subsequently, make sure that you're not dealing with the note from your own post:

> Environment variables may override this value

**Make sure that:**

- NGINX/Apache is setting production mode via an environment variable (as opposed to developer or default), e.g.: `set $MAGE_MODE production;` (NGINX)
- You are using the standard VCL code
- You have cleared PHP OPcache - potentially, you are running with `validate_timestamps = Off`, and the PHP-FPM pool is still running in developer mode until the cache is pruned.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's normal if you're using Magento version **>= 2.4.4**.
Because the code has changed in the varnish6.vcl.

Now the code is as the following:

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
        set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
    }
```

Now **X-Magento-Cache-Debug** header is included in all deployment modes.

For more information:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.4/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish6.vcl#L210